# how to process frames in an event-driven manner with Opencv

Tags: python, opencv, multiprocessing, event-driven

I use Opencv to display real-time frames, When a remote flag variable(which is saved in firebase in this case) changes from `False` to `True`, the program saves current frame. But **polling** flag value makes the program slow and the frames are not smoothly displayed.So I am wondering if it is possible to make it "event-driven".

Here is what I want to do: 
One process captures the frames and display them, like:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
```

Another process gets the variable value, and when it equals True, I send a signal to the main process to save the current frame.

I tried to use `multiprocessing` and `pipe` like:

```
def is_asked(conn):
    while(True):
        isAsked = firebase.get('/test/isAsked', None)        
        conn.send(isAsked)


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=is_asked, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while(True):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)
        # Display the frame
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

        recvSignal = parent_conn.recv()
        print recvSignal
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & recvSignal == True:
           ## do something like take screenshot

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    p.join()
```

But then I realized `parent_conn.recv()` could be blocked by `send()` in `is_asked`, it doesn's make much difference with directly polling.

So is there any "event-driven" way to notify the main process only when the variable changes to True?